# How do I make Parse Queries distinct so that they do not affect one another?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

How do I isolate a Parse Query so that it doesn't influence other queries?  Right now my code looks like:

```
query.include("thing");
query.find({
     success: function(results){
     //there are results here as expected
     }
})

query2.doesNotExist("something");
query2.find({
      success: function(items){
      //there are items here as expected
     }
})


query.exists("key");
query.find({
     success: function(keys){
     //there are no results here but if I reverse the order of the queries . . .
     }
})
```

Now if I put these queries in a different order, where I put the last query above first I get the expected results.

```
query.exists("key");
query.find({
     success: function(keys){
     //there are no results here but if I reverse the order of the queries . . .
     }
})


query.include("thing");
query.find({
     success: function(results){
     //there are results here as expected
     }
})

query2.doesNotExist("something");
query2.find({
      success: function(items){
      //there are items here as expected
     }
})
```

It seems as if the two Parse Queries for 'query' affect one another.  How can I get around this so that each query is distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it doesn't look like you can continue with one query in Parse.  However you can create a new Parse.Query on the same table/collection.